# Calculating Summations in R without loops

Tags: r

So I have this example:

Σ <sub>i=1</sub> <sup>32</sup>
√ i^(3)+log(5)

Which I need to solve using coding in R.

My coding for this is:

```
i<-seq(from=1,to=32)
sqrt((i)^3+log(5))
sum(sqrt((i)^3+log(5)))
```

But i'm not sure if it's correct.
Any hints?

Comment: looks fine (if the square root is to apply to the full expression rather than just the i^3)

Comment: did you run it? do you get the desired result?

Comment: @user2957945 yes the square root applies to the whole thing. Thank you for your feedback. Yes it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check things like this by running on smaller examples that you can convince yourself are working by doing the calculation manually. So...

Your code:

```
> i<-seq(from=1,to=32)
> sum(sqrt((i)^3+log(5)))
[1] 2409.853
```

that's a sum of 32 things: `sqrt(1^3 + log(5) + sqrt(2^3 + log(5)) +` etc. Hard to type all that out. So let's try it with 1 thing:

```
> i<-seq(from=1,to=1)
> sum(sqrt((i)^3+log(5)))
[1] 1.615375
```

Now we can check that by running:

```
> sqrt(1^3+log(5))
[1] 1.615375
```

Okay, looks good. Let's try two things. Your code:

```
> i<-seq(from=1,to=2)
> sum(sqrt((i)^3+log(5)))
[1] 4.715285
```

Compared with the long way round:

```
> sqrt(1^3+log(5)) + sqrt(2^3+log(5))
[1] 4.715285
```

Yay! Now check it for three items and that should convince anyone. Its not a mathematical proof of correctness though. A more complex function might do something unexpected for some values...